# Python addition

Tags: macos, python-3.x, math, addition

Here is what I have tried:

```
name = input("what's your name?")
print("nice to meet you", name,)
num1 = input(int("enter a number (1/2)")
num2 = input(int("enter a number (2/2)")
total = num1 + num2
print(total)
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `int(input())` not `input(int())`

Comment: While python will figure out the casting, you don't cast the dialog to an int, you cast the return variable of input int(input("Words n Stuff"))

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre for helping me with this issue. I would love to mark this as [answered] but have not got enough reputation lol

Comment: that's not how it works. This was a comment, because it's too simple for an answer and, even if I wanted to help you, posting an answer would be "too much" and I'd be considered as a "rep farmer" (which I try not to be). Post a good question in 10 minutes and you'll be able to accept answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While python will figure out the casting, you don't cast the dialog to an int, you cast the return variable of input

Ex : 
val = int(input("Words n Stuff"))